# exec can't execute command on windows

Tags: php, exec

I'm executing php script on windows 10.
The following line execute without any problem:

```
exec("CREATE DATABASE `$dbname`;")
```

but when i want to execute following line i only receive a notice and it doesn't execute:

```
$command='mysql -h' .$dbhost .' -u' .$dbuser .' -p' .$dbpass .' ' .$dbname .' < ' .$mysqlImportFilename;
```

exec($command,$output=null ,$worked);

the notice that i receive:

Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference

The complete script is:

```
$dbhost   = 'localhost';
$dbuser   = 'root';
$dbpass  = '';
$dbname = 'test';
$mysqlImportFilename = 'matab_database_backup.sql';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost", $dbuser, $dbpass);
    
    $dbh->exec("CREATE DATABASE `$dbname`;")
    or die(print_r($dbh->errorInfo(), true));
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("Error: " . $e->getMessage());
}

$command='mysql -h' .$dbhost .' -u' .$dbuser .' -p' .$dbpass .' ' .$dbname .' < ' .$mysqlImportFilename;
exec($command,$output=null ,$worked);
switch($worked)
{
    case 0:
        echo  'Done';
    break;
    case 1:
        echo  'Faild';
    break;
}
```

This script execute on linux well but it doesn't work on windows.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: I found the problem. I only shoud add 'C:/xampp/mysql/bin/' before 'mysql -h dbhost -u dbuser -p dbpass dbname < backupName.sql'.